# What are these two rectangular, black components?

Tags: identification, components, ipod

What are these two components from an iPhod Shuffle 3rd gen (A1271)?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

SMD tantalum capacitors [The "J" means 6.3 V](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/capacitors/capacitor-codes-markings.php). I don't know what the value is, but, from the size, I'd say around 30 to 100 uF.